# Change Header TEXT Links for IMAGE LINKS (for 'My Wishlist')

Tags: magento, icons, toplink

I am using Magento 1.8.1, and I couldn't find any solution to replace the text link 'My Wishlist' for icons/image links for my Mobile responsive version.

This post is following one of my previous post that you can see in the following [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82903/change-header-text-links-for-image-links-for-my-account-my-wishlist-my-c)

However the code provided for the Wishlist is not working when I do the change in my Layout.xml with either the following one:

```
<customer_account>
<reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="removeLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active">
            <name>wishlist</name>
            <path>wishlist/</path>
            <label></label>
            <aParams>class="top-link-wishlist"</aParams>
        </action>
</reference>
</customer_account>
```

or the following one:

```
<layout>
...
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
        <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName><aParams>class="top-link-wishlist"</aParams></action>
    </reference>
</layout>
```

So my question is where is my mistake?

Comment: app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template\links.phtml
change in this file

Comment: it does not help, the change has to be done through the local.xml from the theme layout

Comment: What is the exact problem? Is the link removed at least? Or is there an error? Is the CSS class added? Please be more precise.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot see my Wishlist icon without being logged in. I have error message with the second one. with the mentioned second code I believe the class "top-link-wishlist" is declared thus I use it on my css as below:

  .links li a.top-link-wishlist {background: url(../images/my_starlist.png) no-repeat left 100%; background-size: 25px 25px; padding: 20px 0px 0px 30px; position: static; width: 10%;}

Comment: What does the error message say? Is the HTML for the wishlist there or is it not (when not logged in) - i guess yes, since you are stating "top-link-wishlist" is there. CSS is hard to debug, when not seeing the whole site. Maybe you can give a URL?

Comment: @NiGe sorry for late response, actually the error come from with the first code not with the second. With the second code there is nothing change. I can send you my url by emial since it is under production at the moment.
My email address is: joel.bouton24@gmail.com

Comment: @NiGe Hello, I still having my issue and I can't solve it. If you have time thank you to send me a mail for me to let you see the site.